# How to design endpoints for bi-directional entity mapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa, spring-rest

There are two entities, `User` and `Order`. The `User` entity has a `Set<Order>` of orders, and it's a bi-directional mapping.

Now I have two controllers, one controller is called `OrderController` and it has some endpoints to retrieve all orders, etc. The second controller is called `UserController` and it has some endpoints related to the user, but it also has endpoints such as `/users/{username}/orders` and `/users/{username}/orders/{orderId}`.

The question is where should I add an endpoint to persist an order? Should it be a `POST` in `OrderController` i.e. `/orders` or should it be in `UserController` as `/users/{username}/orders` endpoint? Orders are created by a user and the `OrderController` is only used to retrieve all orders, not only for the specific user.

Do you have any tips on how should it be designed?

Comment: I wouldn’t nest orders under users. Just because a user has a set of orders doesn’t mean it “owns” the orders. If they’re independently persisted entities with their own ids - i.e globally unique then just have `/orders/orderid`.

Comment: In this case the orders are dependent on users, because when we delete a user, then all his orders will be deleted. User should be able to add orders, edit them etc, so there should be an endpoint in user controller I believe. Order controller is used to see all the orders. WDYT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zalando API Guideline](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#146) has some view on this matter which they suggest we SHOULD limit the number of resource types because of the following reasons :

> To keep maintenance and service evolution manageable, we should follow
> "functional segmentation" and "separation of concern" design
> principles and do not mix different business functionalities in same
> API definition. In practice this means that the number of resource
> types exposed via an API should be limited. In this context a resource
> type is defined as a set of highly related resources such as a
> collection, its members and any direct sub-resources.

Apply to your case , basically they suggest only has the following resource types :

- /users
- /orders

And no need to have `/users/{username}/orders/` as `/orders` already serve the same purpose. If you want to get orders for an user , simply use `/orders?user=foobar`

Comment: do I need in this case call the` getOrders()` method on a user, or does it make sense to create a new method in the repository to retrieve all orders by a user?